# Magento2 default 404 page not showing

Tags: magento2, 404-page

I have set **404 page** in admin `stores > configuration` but for some reason its not loading on frontend urls , its throwing following error:

Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Can anyone let me know the solution?

[image]

Comment: Same problem here! Need help please

Comment: did anyone found solution for this issue?